# registerNewUser new user in lotus notes in different database than names.nsf

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

When I am creating/registering a new user in Lotus Notes using registerNewUser (i.e. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_REGISTERNEWUSER_METHOD_JAVA.html)

the new user is getting added to names.nsf file. which is default file of Lotus Notes address book.

I want to create/register a User in custom.nsf/other than names.nsf file. How I can do that using ncso.jar API?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility to register a user in another addressbook.

There is no possibility in the admin client and therefore no backend functions to do so.

To do that, you have to register the user "normally" and then copy the document over to the other addressbook (don't forget to delete to original one).